# Перехват json ответа в Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, requests, selenium-webdriver

Есть сайт forexample.com с множеством скриптов из которого мне нужно достать данные. Данные отображаются в табличном виде с большим количеством столбцов, которые не помещаются на страницу и потому там реализован скроллинг влево-вправо.

С помощью Selenium, обращаясь к url='forexample.com', данные я достал, но только те, которые находятся в видимой части, потому что значения у скрытых столбцов '&nbsp';

Пробовал полностраничный режим - все-равно все столбцы не умещаются на странице.

При исследовании запросов в режиме разработчика, вижу, что при запросе браузер отправляет несколько POST запросов еще на адрес url='forexample.com/a' с параметрами, содержащими количество страниц, сортировкой и прочими в json и получает ответ в json, однако использовать библиотеку requests не могу, так как к запросу добавляются еще и X-Ajax-Token и X-Csrftoken, без которых сервер не хочет отдавать данные.

Вопрос: Каким образом в Selenium можно перехватить json ответ на запрос по адресу url='forexample.com/a', которые делает браузер без головоломки с получением и формированием X-Ajax-Token и X-Csrftoken?

Comment: "Пробовал полностраничный режим - все-равно все столбцы не умещаются на странице".а вы не пробывали прокрутить страницу?

Comment: Если прокручивать вправо, чтобы отобразились правые столбцы, тогда скроются левые (((

Comment: Попытался перехватить данные с помощью прокси и библиотеки BrowserMob Proxy. Но почему-то перехватываются далеко не все данные. Как мне кажется только данные запроса. Данных ответа сервера нет. К тому же Хром ругается о небезопасности соединения и не хочет сразу загружать страницу, а только если нажимать "все равно перейти".

Comment: библиотека playwright имеет в своем арсенале возможность перехвата запросов

Comment: Решил проблему увеличением размера окна и установкой максимальной ширины секции: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.maxWidth = '3000px';", section). Но библиотеку playwright надо бы попробовать, так как данные на странице отображаются не все, которые приходят в json.